# underscorejs each function is not working

Tags: javascript, logging, underscore.js

as seen below, and I am trying using the -.each function from underscorejs to assign the value of each record in the json file and print it to the screen.. I have this code but it doesn't work... any ideas why?

```
var ty = [{
    "Language": "en-GB",
"Section": "Sales&Marketing",
"ItemName": "CalculationType",
"Texts": "Having selected the account heading select the calculation ..."},
{"Language": "en-GB",
"Section": "Taxes",
"ItemName": "Save",
"Texts": "The Master Tax Table has been pre populated with the current UK, ..."}
];

arr= {};
_.each(ty, function(val,key) {
   arr[key] = val;
});
log(arr);
```

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Is underscore defined? Why you don't use `ty.forEach` instead?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the result you're getting right now?

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to log all the properties of the json.. like Language : UK etc

Comment: @JeBokE no errors just a blank screen

Comment: @dloeda what do you mean defined? like a cdn? because i didnt find any

Comment: @Geaorge  did you include the file underscore.js into this js file http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js like if (typeof someObject == 'undefined') $.loadScript('underscore.js', function(){ }

Comment: or if it's html page then directly include over it by html java script tag

Comment: @GeorgeXReplay I mean if `_` is defined. Also, if there are any error at developer console

Comment: I am running the code and it returns the two objects as it should. Are you sure you included Underscore before your own js file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Even if you use a foreach and then inside a for in loop, you will end up overriding the property values for each iteration of the outer loop

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/george944/1u5j0z1e/3/ that is a short version of the code @dloeda   got all the libraries in but still aint works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/george944/1u5j0z1e/3/ that is a short version of the code   @TusharPal got all the libraries in but still aint works

Comment: The problem in your jsfiddle in your log function, if you replace `log` by `console.log` works and add jQuery lib

Comment: @dloeda that's not the problem... i have tried it

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with the CDN. If you want language then you need to assign `val.Language`.And also array definition wrong.Give `new Array` or `[]` instead of `{}`.Try the below one:

```js
function log(contents) {
var result='';
if(_.isArray(contents)) {
    _.each(contents, function(e, i, l) {
        //log(e);
        result += e.Language+'-'+e.Section+'-'+e.ItemName+'-'+e.Texts+'</br>';
    });
} 
return result;
};


var ty = [{
"Language": "en-GB",
"Section": "Sales&Marketing",
"ItemName": "CalculationType",
"Texts": "Having selected the account heading select the calculation ..."},
{"Language": "en-GB",
"Section": "Taxes",
"ItemName": "Save",
"Texts": "The Master Tax Table has been pre populated with the current UK, ..."}
];

arr= new Array;
_.each(ty, function(val,key) {
   arr[key] = val;
});
var res=log(arr);
$('#result').append(res);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking this one? @George X Replay

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/1u5j0z1e/4/... when i add the cdn it works..check that in console

Comment: still nothing.. the results box is empty. does it work for you?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1u5j0z1e/11/ ..it is working now ..i updated as you want

Comment: but this only prints "en-GBen-GBen-GBen-GB" I want to print everything in an order...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148213/discussion-between-george-x-replay-and-lalithkumar).

Comment: why is does it print it from the log function? and not from the last line? you answer was invalid

Comment: I send you the fiddle file, remember? with all the code

Comment: That you sent after i posted the answer..And also what you have edited in my answer ...what is aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?